# Does Selenium's LoadableComponent make sense in a SPA (Single Page Application)?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2

I'm writing a UI testing suite for a single page javascript application using Selenium 2 web driver.  I'm still experimenting with how to fit the app inside a page object model.  At the moment I am considering the use of the Selenium [LoadableComponent](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/LoadableComponent) pattern for various subpages in the application.

The `isLoaded()` function makes sense since I frequently need to make check certain elements are visible/enabled to determine if the the subpage is correctly loaded.  On the other hand I can't really figure out how to make use of the `load()` method, since a subpage is not directly accessible by a URL, but rather requires navigating through the app. All the examples I have found use URLs to navigate in the `load()`?

Anyone have experience or design pattern ideas with automated SPA javascript apps? Basically I want to be able to navigate and wait for things to load as cleanly as possible.

More on LoadableComponent: [Is Selenium's LoadableComponent a good solution as test design pattern?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/is-seleniums-loadablecomponent-a-good-solution-as-test-design-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you what I do in this situation.  I have not used the LoadableComponent, however what I have done has followed a similar pattern.  I create classes for each of the "loadable components" that are basically page objects.  I have something like the IsLoaded function to ensure that the component is loaded, and depending on how it works I either don't implement a Load function at all, or I have the load function go through the clicks to get the component to load.  For example, if loading a component simply means clicking on an item in a menu or some other simple action or sequence of actions, I implement the load function.  If it requires doing something more complex such as filling out a form first, I usually do not.

In the case where I don't have a Load function, I usually call the IsLoaded functions within other helper functions, so for example if I have a sign up page, I have a function called SignUp that will fill in the form and then call IsLoaded on the page/component that should be loaded next.

Comment: Yup.  Working through it in C#, I ended up with simple `IsLoaded()` and `HasDisappeared()` functions using the `WebDriverWait` `Until()` to check for elements on the loading or un-loading screen.  So I think the pattern make sense, but not necessarily needing the LoadableComponent interface.